# how can I remove all words that start with sequence of characters

Tags: c#, regex

How can I remove all words that start with  a defined sequence of characters .

Example: remove each word that start with "ARC"

blabla ARC-01 blablabla ARC-02 ... (result)   =>  blabla  blablabla  ...

I have try many thing with Regex but I'm a little bit lost with that.

Comment: Can you paste your regex to help you

Comment: I was far from a valid result... The answer (below) from anubhava come with regex test tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to find:

```
\bARC\S*\s*
```

and replace by empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU2eH7/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
(?=\bARC)[^\s]+
```

And replace with `''` (empty string)